# What is "approximation in a Sobolev Space"? For example,

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I want to know the meaning of the statement as below.

$$ \text{There is a sequence} \;\{f_k\} \subset W^{3,2}\; \text{approximating}\;\; f \;\;\text{in}\;\; W^{2,2}. $$

Here $ W^{n,m} $ means a Sobolev Space.

Comment: Presumably this means that each $f_k$ is in $W^{3,2}$ and $f_k \rightarrow f$ in the norm of $W^{2,2}$ (i.e. $\|f_k - f\|_{W^{2,2}} \rightarrow 0$.)

Comment: @user15464 You could post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this means that each $f_k$ is in $W^{3,2}$ and $f_k\rightarrow f$ in the norm of $W^{2,2}$ (i.e. $\|f_k-f\|_{W^{2.2}}\rightarrow 0$).